# Buffering Youtube video in Firefox (api)

Tags: firefox, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, buffering

I noticed that in Firefox with html5 embeddedd videos if I embed a youtube video the video buffers like crazy even if the video is paused. In Chrome the buffering is managed though. Is this a known bug?
Is there a possibility to manage the buffering via the youtube api. I saw several plugins for Firefox to control it. (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/)Is there a way to control Buffering through the Javascript of the site itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs to control buffering, and in general, it's something that's controlled by logic in the player. There are several factors that come into play, including some that could be browser-related. It's intentionally a black box from a developer perspective.

Comment: Thats what I thought :-( Just got to wait for Firefox or Youtube to support HTML 5 Video properly...